# How come execution time in TOAD is higher then manually calculating execution time with SYSTIMESTAMP?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, toad

I have a procedure with a lot of select statements. When I run the procedure the execution time in TOAD's Query Viewer tab is much higher then the calculated execution time using SYSTIMESTAMP at the beginning and end of the procedure.

**Procedure:**

```
DECLARE

/* Declare Variables */

BEGIN

    /* Initalize Variables */
    startTime number;
    endTime number;
    totalTime number;

    startTime :=  to_number(TO_CHAR (SYSTIMESTAMP, 'MISS.FF' )); 
    dbms_output.put_line('Start Procedure: '||startTime );

    /* Execute a lot of SQL */

    endTime :=   to_number(TO_CHAR (SYSTIMESTAMP, 'MISS.FF'  )); 
    dbms_output.put_line('End Procedure: '||endTime );

    totalTime := endTime-startTime;

    dbms_output.put_line('Total Time in Seconds: '||totalTime );
END;
```

**DBMS Output:**

```
Start Procedure: 3645.427147
End Procedure: 3645.427618
Total Time in Seconds: .000471
```

So the calculated time is .471 ms, but TOAD says it's 146ms.

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: Toad times the complete process from when the statement is sent to the database until execution has completed and a return notification is received. This will include any time needed for network activity as well as any setup/teardown code required by Toad to send the statement to Oracle and process results. The time shown in Toad is the amount of execution time that you experience after you click execute until Toad has results for you. If you want accurate execution time on the database then you'll need another method as suggested by "be here now."

Comment: I think a mixture of Michael's comment and "Be Here Now"'s answer is a good enough answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all wall clock time which may vary - you don't know how exactly TOAD measures it, for instance. I wouldn't consider TOAD trustworthy. If you want accurate measurement, use either [DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME/GET_CPU_TIME](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_util.htm#i1003768), or [sql trace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/sqltrace.htm) - they are to do this by design.